# Setting precedence and associativity in Bison without %prec or %left

Tags: compiler-construction, bison, yacc, lex, flex-lexer

How could you set precedence and associativity in Bison without using %prec or %left? Is there a way to write the grammar where it would not be necessary?

Answer (score 10):

If you don't want to use `%prec`, `%left`, and `%right`, you have to use multiple nonterminals to establish precedence.

For example, consider this grammar:

```
%token NUMBER
%left '+'
%left '*'
%right '^'

%%

expression
    : NUMBER
    | expression '+' expression
    | expression '*' expression
    | expression '^' expression
    | '(' expression ')'
    ;

%%
```

Let's see how it matches the expression `1 + 2 * 3`.  If we remove the precedence directives from the grammar above, then the grammar can match this expression in two ways.  Here's one way:

```
expression(+)
    |
    +-- expression(NUMBER 1)
    |
    +-- expression(*)
            |
            +-- expression(NUMBER 2)
            |
            +-- expression(NUMBER 3)
```

Here's the other way:

```
expression(*)
    |
    +-- expression(+)
    |       |
    |       +-- expression(NUMBER 1)
    |       |
    |       +-- expression(NUMBER 2)
    |
    +-- expression(NUMBER 3)
```

We want to write a grammar that can only match like the first way, where `*` binds more tightly than `+`.  We have to create new nonterminals and split the `expression` nonterminal's productions among the new nonterminals, like this:

```
%token NUMBER

%%

primaryExpression
    : NUMBER
    | '(' expression ')'
    ;

exponentiationExpression
    : primaryExpression
    // Right-recursion makes this right-associative.
    | primaryExpression '^' exponentiationExpression
    ;

multiplicationExpression
    : exponentiationExpression
    // Left recursion makes this left-associative.
    | multiplicationExpression '*' exponentiationExpression
    ;

additionExpression
    : multiplicationExpression
    | additionExpression '+' multiplicationExpression
    ;

expression
    : additionExpression
    ;
```

Let's look at how this grammar matches the expression `1 + 2 * 3`.  It can only match this way:

```
expression
    |
    +-- additionExpression
            |
            +-- additionExpression
            |       |
            |       +-- multiplicationExpression
            |               |
            |               +-- exponentiationExpression
            |                   |
            |                   +-- primaryExpression(NUMBER 1)
            |
            +-- multiplicationExpression
                    |
                    +-- multiplicationExpression
                    |       |
                    |       +-- exponentiationExpression
                    |               |
                    |               +-- primaryExpression(NUMBER 2)
                    |
                    +-- exponentiationExpression
                            |
                            +-- primaryExpression(NUMBER 3)
```

Although there are more levels in the parse tree now, it matches the desired binding precedence.

If you want to write your grammar this way, keep in mind that LALR parsers generally use much more memory when handling right recursion than when handling left recursion.  So it's common to rewrite the right recursion (used in `exponentiationExpression`) as left recursion, and fix up the associativity in code.

Answer (score 1):

Yes -- you can use separate rules for different levels of precedence, and control associativity via left vs. right recursion. For example, to get `+` and `-` with lower precedence than `*` and `/`, one left associative and the other right<sup>1</sup>, you could do something like this:

```
number: literal | variable;

mul_expr: number
        | mul_expr MUL_OP number
        ;

add_expr: mul_expr
        | mul_expr ADD_OP add_expr
        ;
```

And yes, this is really yacc-like pseudo-code; I'm sure yacc, byacc, Bison, etc. would reject it as-is.

---

<sup>1</sup> Yes, those are normally all left associative, but I'm just doing this to demonstrate how to make something right-associative if you want to.